# which is more efficent, INNER JOIN vs smaller UPDATE queries

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join, entity-attribute-value

say i have a whole bunch of tables using an EAV (Entity Attribute Value) structure, i can update 20 values for 1 entity using a whole lot of inner joins in the query

which is more efficient, using all these inner joins or having 20 smaller queries which update 1 value at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of single row inner queries is more efficient and for multiple row insert you can can go for inner joins